# Google API Quota Limits for Youtube API

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Hi I'm new to Youtube API. I have problem in Quotas in Youtube API.

Youtube API allows to use only 10,000 quota points per day. My project is fully based on uploading videos to a Youtube Channel. For a single video upload(insert) through API it cost upto 1600 points,  with this i can upload only 6 videos per day. I have applied for Quota increase. I don't know when my quota will be increased. But my Quotas Dashboard confusing me, it shows [image]

it allows 1,800,000 queries per minute and it will allow only 10,000 queries per Day. If Youtube API can allow 1,800,000 queries/minute then Queries per day must be in Millions! In which basis I'm getting this Quotas Dashboard.

Comment: How are you getting this this quota page?  Mine looks completely different?

Comment: This page only shows for me! I don't have idea about another UI of quota management page. Bcz I'm completely confused

Comment: @CrazyDeveloper have you found anything on this?

Answer (score 0):

That quota is normal. A possible explanation for the quotas they are giving us could be that their biggest worry are not so much users firing 1000 requests very quickly in a short time frame but users firing 100 000 querys throughout the whole day. I've witnessed a similar issue with a thirparty provider that screenscraped a website. These people were so stupid they didnt cache anything and created much load on the site. Since they didn't react on complaints the only choice was to block them completly. Youtube uses a finer grained approach.

Comment: I understand about quota but I'm confused about my Quotas Dashboard. Please understand my question before answer